# Capybara 3 normalize whitespace

Tags: cucumber, capybara

I've just updated Capybara to version 3.13.

I've noticed that you can add an option to assertions using, `normalize_ws: true`.  For my existing test packs, updating every assertion to use this would be time consuming.

Can this be set in the env.rb file of your cucumber project to be invoked by default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set `Capybara.default_normalize_ws = true`, although you should start updating your assertions to match what a user actually sees because the option will probably go away in Capybara 4

Comment: I do intend to do it when the sprints calm down a bit.  This is intended to just be a temporary measure.  Thank you.

Comment: I have placed that in my env.rb file but sadly, it hasn't worked

Comment: @Tom define “doesn’t work”,. Do you get an error, what assertions are you using? It would only affect assertions that accept the `normalize_ws` option.

Comment: Sorry.  I have some assertions that are just using expect(attr).to have_text(bla) and the test is failing as it is still expecting "\n" in the string.

Comment: @Tom if the have_text expects \n and you set default_normalize_ws then it would fail because the \n would be removed - you can’t have it both ways

Comment: I understand, I have the default_normalise_ws set and my expectation does not include the \n but that is how Capybara sees the string, as "words\nwords"

Comment: @Tom It's behavior that's tested in the capybara test suite - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/spec/session/has_text_spec.rb#L50 - so given your info provided either the `have_text` you're calling isn't from Capybara, or you're using per session config mode ("threadsafe" mode) and have created the session before setting the global option